# Query unknown number of keywords in Postgres

Tags: sql, node.js, postgresql, relational-division, node-postgres

I'm currently using postgres in node to query all users who have a certain tag associated with their account like so (note: I'm using [node-postgres](https://github.com/brianc/node-postgres)):

```
query = 'SELECT tags.*, pl.email FROM admin.tags tags
LEFT JOIN gameday.player_settings pl
ON tags.player_id = pl.id
WHERE tags.tag = $1'

client.query(
  query,
  [tagName],
  function(err, results) {
    ...
```

`[tagName]` is then passed into the `WHERE` clause.

What I'm aiming to do is instead query by an unknown number of tags and return all users who have all of those tags associated with their account. So instead of `[tagName]` I'd like to pass in an array of unknown length, `[tagNames]`, but I'm not sure how to accomplish this.

Comment: Where are you passing in the data *from*? Can you [edit] to make that clearer, and add an example of the code you need to integrate with?

Comment: @IMSoP, details added above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to turn the question backwards. Instead of:

*Which users have all of these tags*, you need to ask *which users do not have one or more of these tags absent*. It's a double negation.

You also need a way to pass the set of tags. The best way to do this, if the client language binding supports it, is as an array-valued query parameter. If the client binding doesn't support array-valued parameters you'll need dynamic SQL.

One formulation might be (untested, since you didn't provide sample schema and data):

```
SELECT pl.email
FROM gameday.player_settings pl
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT 1
  FROM unnest(?) AS wanted_tags(tag)
  LEFT JOIN admin.tags tags
    ON tags.tag = wanted_tags.tag
  WHERE  tags.player_id = pl.id
    AND wanted_tags.tag IS NULL
);
```

Doing a left join and filtering for `IS NULL` is called a left anti-join. It *keeps* the rows where the left-join condition does *not* match. So in this case, we retain a tag from our `wanted_tags` array only if there is *no matching tag associated with this player*. If any tags are left, the `WHERE NOT EXISTS` returns false, so the player is excluded.

Double-think, isn't it? It's easy to make mistakes with this so *test*.

Here `?` should be your programming language PostgreSQL database binding's query parameter placeholder. I don't know what node.js's is. This will only work if you can pass an array as a query parameter in node. If not, you'll have to use dynamic SQL to generate an `ARRAY['x','y','z']` expression or a `(VALUES ('x'), ('y'), ('z'))` subquery.

P.S. Please provide *sample schema and data* with questions when possible. http://sqlfiddle.com/ is handy.

Comment: Thank you, and it looks like there is a way to pass an array of values according to the node-postgres [FAQ](https://github.com/brianc/node-postgres/wiki/FAQ) question 11.

Comment: According to [this bug report it supports arrays now](https://github.com/brianc/node-postgres/issues/129#issuecomment-48633017) so the FAQ might be outdated. [Confirmation](https://github.com/brianc/node-postgres/issues/82#issuecomment-18756081).

Comment: @MattDionis The FAQ suggests that the driver does *not* support arrays natively (even though those bugs contradict it), and illustrates a way to do it using dynamic SQL. It still uses parameters to avoid SQL injection, but the query string has to be dynamically generated each time. So if possible you should prefer to use node-postgres's support for passing JavaScript arrays as parameters directly.

Comment: @MattDionis I've updated the FAQ. Please test and confirm, since I don't use node-postgres myself.

Comment: I'll be testing this out later today and I'll report back. Thank you very much for the help!

Comment: [pg-promise](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise) has proper support for the [WHERE IN](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise/wiki/Learn-by-Example#where-col-in-values) case.